# ASP How to bind the selected value of a dropdownlist in detailsview

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, detailsview

I have a dropdownlist in a detailsview control. The data source is a SQL table with a dayofthemonth column.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Day of Month: ">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDoM" runat="server" > 
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dayofthemonth") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("dayofthemonth") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have populated the dropdownlist with numbers 1 - 31 in the DataBound event.

```
protected void DataView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddlDoM = (DropDownList)Page.FindControl("ctl00$formPlaceHolder$DataView1$ddlDoM");
    if (DataView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Edit)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 32; i++)
        {
            ListItem item = ListItem.FromString(i.ToString());
            ddlDoM.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
        DataRowView drv = DataView1.DataItem as DataRowView;
        ddlDoM.SelectedIndex = ddlDoM.Items.IndexOf(ddlDoM.Items.FindByValue(drv["dayofthemonth"].ToString()));
    }
}
```

In the final line here, I set the selected value of the dropdownlist to the current data source value.

`ddlDoM.SelectedIndex = ddlDoM.Items.IndexOf(ddlDoM.Items.FindByValue(drv["dayofthemonth"].ToString()));`

How can I bind the dropdownlist to update the value in the datasource when changed? I have tried setting the selected value property to `<%# Bind("dayofthemonth") %>`, but I receive an OutOfRangeException. I'm assuming the list hasn't populated yet in switching to Edit Mode.

Any thoughts on this? Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP - please re-tag to ASP.NET.

Comment: my mistake, thanks for catching

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `ControlParameter` to your `UpdateParameters` in your datasource, and ensure your dropdown list is set to AutoPostBack if appropriate. You might also consider populating the dropdownlist in an earlier event (e.g. `Page_Init`) and leave setting its default value until the DataBound event you already have.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ... UpdateCommand=""....>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDoM" Name="dayofthemonth" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Also, if it's still causing problems, a safe (but verbose) option is to add the ListItems directly to the dropdownlist control, because they seem to be static values:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDoM" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Value="3" />
    etc...
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I followed these steps and I now get the error `Could not find control 'ddlDoM' in ControlParameter 'dayofthemonth'. ` Could this be because the control is not present unless the DetailsView is in Edit mode? How can I get around this?

Comment: @NickOban: Sorry, my original code was more concerned with select parameters, but you're looking for update parameters. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again, Michael. This is definitely closer, but now I'm back to the OutOfRangeException. `'ddlDoM' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value `I think this may be a life cycle problem. I need to know if there is an event that fires before data binding of the ddlDoM but after it has been created (when switching to Edit mode). I'll continue using the verbose ListItem solution for now.

Comment: @NickOban: Did you try populating the dropdownlist in `Page_Init`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I think the problem is that the ddlDoM control isn't created for the code to find. `(DropDownList)Page.FindControl("ctl00$formPlaceHolder$DataView1$ddlDoM");` returns `null` and the CurrentMode of my DetailsView is still ReadOnly.

Comment: @NickOban: Yeah, that makes sense I guess, but there are a lot of other events you could try that might hit the right place in the life cycle. For example, `DetailsView.ModeChanged`